ANTLR4: Break on new line or EOL for ADD
I am creating a new new grammar file for Natural-adabas Language. As a starting point I have relied on ChatGPT for generating the initial grammar syntax.
I am facing an issue in the below, as the addOperation is not correctly breaking on EOL or newLine and its incorrectly going further over the code
addOperation
    : ADD .*? (END_OF_LINE)
    ;

code snippet
7740       IF TURN-ON-MISC-PAY-FORM-IND(7730) = 'Y' THEN DO
7750         ADD 1 TO #B
7760         RESET #MISC-TRANSACTION-ENTRY

Tried multiple combinations of end of line or new line characters in the lexer file.

The .* inside a parser does not match what a .* inside a lexer rule matches. Inside a lexer rule it matches zero or more characters, but inside a parser rule, it matches zero or more tokens. So if  1 TO #B is not handled by any lexer rule, the parser rule addOperation will not match the input. Besides that, a .* inside a parser rule is (usually) a bad idea to begin with.

As a starting point I have relied on ChatGPT for generating the initial grammar syntax.

I recommend really learning ANTLR instead of "learning" from an AI model.
